# Form input submission using ajax to stop a page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, refresh

I wish to use forms to input data to an e-commerce cart I use, but wish to do this without the page refreshing after the user clicks the 'add to cart' button from the form. I have found many examples of submitting a form without a page refresh using jquery eg:
[Submit A Form Without Page Refresh using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057840/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery) 
however have been unable to get this to work despite trying a few different solutions.

My form:

```
<form method="POST" id="formname">
<input name="userid" id="userid" value="00000000" type="hidden">
<input name="product" id="product" value="product name" type="hidden">
<input name="price" id="price" value="1.00" type="hidden">
<input name="qty" id="qty" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="nocart" id="nocart" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="units" id="units" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="scode" id="scode" value="xxxx" type="hidden">
<input name="hash" id="hash" value="xxxxxxxx" type="hidden">
<input name="return" id="return" value="http://www.returnaddresshere" type="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

and the script:

```
<script src="jquerylocation.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#formname").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var userid = $("#userid").val();
    var product = $("#product").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    var nocart = $("#nocart").val();
    var units = $("#units").val();
    var scode = $("#scode").val();
    var hash = $("#hash").val();
    var return = $("#return").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://ww#.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm",
        data: "userid=" + userid + "&product=" + product "price=" + price + "&qty=" + qty "nocart=" + nocart + "&units=" + units "scode=" + scode + "&hash=" + hash + "&return=" + return,
        success: function(){alert('order added to cart');}
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I am not sure where the problem lies as I'm very new to javascript and jquery. All the examples I have seen use php as well to handle the input from the forms; would the fact that the e-commerce uses coldfusion require a different approach?

Thank you in advance your help.

Comment: Did you include the main jquery javascript library? Check your browser console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url: "http://ww#.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm",` is the culprit here
You cannot send an Ajax Request to another domain than the other on which your application is deployed. This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) implemented in web-browers -- a security measure.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, it is very much appreciated.